# Javascript math.random() in a loop with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, html5-canvas

So I want a rectangle of my canvas to change the color from black to yellow, to show that this same part have received an information. There is two rectangles from 2 diferent paths, and I want them to change the color in a random way.

If one rectangle is "0" and the other is "1", for example, when I press the button "Begin", math.random() will choose it to be 1 and rectangle "1" will change it's color from black to yellow. The loop will happen again and if math.random() choose it to be 0, now it's the rectangle 0 that will change it's color. And so on, until I press the "End" button.

This is what I tried to write on javascript:

```
iniciarButton.onclick = function (e) {
    iniciarButton.disabled = true;
    pararButton.disabled = false;
    for (;;) {
        var numAleat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        if (numAleat === 1) {
            context.fillStyle = "yellow";
            context.fillRect(715,140,10,15);
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillRect(642,80,15,10);
        } else {
            context.fillStyle = "yellow";
            context.fillRect(642,80,15,10);
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillRect(715,140,10,15);
        }
        if (iniciarButton.disabled === false) break;
    }
};


pararButton.onclick = function (e) {
    pararButton.disabled = true;
    iniciarButton.disabled = false;
};
```

The problem is that it isn't working the way I expected it. When I press the "begin" button it enters on a loop that ends on one rectangle yellow and the other black and not like blinking in a random way.

Comment: Did you check that both if's are executed?
Replace the context.fillStyle and .fillRect with console.log("IF") in the if and console.log("ELSE") in the else. Run it and see if both are executed. Then report back please.

Comment: Oh, I haven't checked yet. But yes, they are both executed.

Comment: That's important to know. So now that we're sure of it, it seems that despite the two branches of logic are entered like they should, it has no visual effect. Maybe it's just happening too quick? Try setInterval: `var intervalID = setInterval(function(){function_body_here;}, 5000);` then `clearInterval(intervalID);` to clear it (when iniciarButton becomes `disabled`

Comment: @PawelP is on the right track.  Create some time lapse between drawing otherwise both your rects will rapidly blink black-yellow: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dwygdzzp/

Comment: @markE - your code works nicely. You should really post this as an answer.

Comment: Wow, guys, thank you very much for your help! I'm learning javascript now, and still getting used to it. It's for my final big work at college. Thank you again.